# Области видимости JS. Различие между ES6 () =>{} и function()

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, область-видимости

В чем различие между `(someVal) => {DoSomething}` и `function(someVal){DoSomething}` ?

Проявилось вот в этом куске кода

```
let latestNews = $('.time-articles');
        latestNews.find('.article.text_bold').each(() => {
        time = $(this).find('.article__time').text()}
```

В этом случае `this` - это `window`

Если заменить на `function()` - то приходят найденные элементы

```
let latestNews = $('.time-articles');
        latestNews.find('.article.text_bold').each(function () {
        time = $(this).find('.article__time').text()}
```

Answer (score 2):

Выражения стрелочных функций имеют более короткий синтаксис по сравнению с функциональными выражениями и лексически привязаны к значению this (но не привязаны к собственному this, arguments, super, или new.target). Стрелочные функции всегда анонимные

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

Стрелочная функция всегда привязывается к тому контексту, в котором она находится.

В Вашем случае `this` нужно заменить на `latestNews`.

Можно переписать Ваш код так:

```
let latestNews = $('.time-articles');
    latestNews.find('.article.text_bold').each(() => {
    time = $(latestNews).find('.article__time').text()}
```

Comment: Замена `this` на `latestNews` здесь приведет совсем к другому результату нежели с использованием `function`. В случае с `function` переменная `this` последовательно примет значения содержимого элементов `.article__time`, а в вашем решении `time` будет иметь идентичное значение на всех итерациях.

Comment: Действительно. В таком случае код можно сократить до двух строк `let latestNews = $('.time-articles');` `time = latestNews.find('.article__time').text();`

Comment: Так тоже не получится, метод `text()` возвращает объединенный текст из всех элементов, здесь лучше вообще отказаться от стрелочной функции, либо для получения текста брать второй ее аргумент.